# How can I find my App's full version number from the mainBundle NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I know I can find the bundle version from the mainBundle NSDictionary via

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

This doesn't gives me the full version though. How do I access the object via the `CFBundleShortVersionString` key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can do something like:

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

You're not limited to *konstants*!